# Generic typing a store of a given type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm creating a custom Redux store that a store should be able to extend. My goal is for something like this:

```
class BaseStore<T> { 
    public state$: Observable<StoreState<T>>;
    ...
    // other helpers and the like
}
```

where `StoreState` looks like:

```
export type ErrorState = Record<string, any>;
export type LoadableState<T> = {
  data: T;
  loading: boolean;
  error: ErrorState;
};
export type StoreState<T> = Record<string, Partial<LoadableState<T>>>;
```

But I can't get the typing just right. This works but if you wanted to have two items in the store like this:

```
{ // this object represents the store which consists of LoadableStates 
      something: { // I want to type the "slices" in the store
        data: { // and also to be able to type what is in data
          todos: [] 
        },
        loading: false,
        error: {}
      },
      somethingElse: {
        data: {
          items: []
        },
        loading: false,
        error: {}
      }
}
```

the whole thing falls apart; meaning, I can't keep typing for something like:

```
interface SomethingState {
  email?: string;
  username?: string;
}

interface SomethingElseState {
  todos?: Array<Record<string,string>>;
  saveSuccess?: Record<string, string | boolean>;
}

interface MyStoreState {
  something?: SomethingState;
  somethingElse?: SomethingElseState;
}

class MyStore extends BaseStore<MyStoreState> {
  ...
  public getEmail(): Observable<string> {
    return this.state$.pipe(map(state => state.something.data.email))
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Can't say I've used generics much so this would be a great learning experience.

Edit: Mapped types seem to have a draw back. The `update()` function for the store wouldn't work:

```
// my implementation for updating the store

public set(nextState: StoreState<T>): void {
  this.state$.next(nextState);
}

public update(storeSlice: string, partialState: Partial<LoadableState<T>>): void {
    if (!this.stateValue[storeSlice]) {
      throw Error('Path does not exist in the store');
    }

    const currentState = this.stateValue[storeSlice];
    const nextState = merge(currentState, partialState); // lodash's merge

    this.set({ [storeSlice]: { ...nextState } }); // ERROR: Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StoreState<T>'
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what "the whole thing falls apart" means, exactly (often a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows what you mean is more helpful than words anyway), but presuming that you'd like to keep track of each key of `state` and the `data` type of its corresponding property, I'd suggest using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to represent `StoreState<T>` in terms of an object type `T` that represents these key/data relationships.

```
type StoreState<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Partial<LoadableState<T[K]>> };
```

Then, assuming `BaseStore<T>` has a constructor that sets its `state` property:

```
class BaseStore<T> {
    constructor(public state: StoreState<T>) { }
}
```

You should be able to construct one using your object:

```
const bs = new BaseStore({
    something: {
        data: {
            todos: [1, 2, 3] // ‍♂️
        },
        loading: false,
        error: {}
    },
    somethingElse: {
        data: {
            items: ["a", "b", "c"] // ‍♀️
        },
        loading: false,
        error: {}
    }
});
```

and you'll see that the type of the constructed object has been inferred (via [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types)) like this:

```
/*
const bs: BaseStore<{
    something: {
        todos: number[];
    };
    somethingElse: {
        items: string[];
    };
}>*/
```

So the inferred `T` here is `{something: {todos: number[]}; somethingElse: {items: string[]};}` as, I think, you wanted.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDKAXA9gJwQHgCoD5oBvAKGnOmDQDsIUMBXYdDACgAcGAjEAS2Gh0wKBAC5oqTMhTCcBAJTFoAXxKqSKAJ7sE0AKIYMmVLOgBeaACUEVDABNsdDL2oBzADTQw1TfgDcGtq6ADJoYHZgPNKyeIQWpBTQETLiuAGJIGF2Lq7iXGhoIAje6RQIhpjiBkYYJiIBygFaOhIs0SKx5koA2gDS0C7QANYImmgAZtC4ALriAApgGCi8YCDYoeGRRXVyfdP4hI0kJFS0KNBcMBbUCADucIiSWKwJFBBoALYIKAAWOeKvRLkZJgAFkIEQ9B2NAQcTdACMngATJ4AMzTcEQ5TuTFAzLhf7QcarCAIHEQ8jlGoA1SJbG495fX45PQgUlgilJYSg4i4zm8EQfWHQboAIjAos8oq4kugouAooxnPpnPx2Tc4mJbLJfLKFQwNNxqmU8gCJAA9AAqE40OgXYXwUlPHCAwSfb5-DW8zlQmHiagMD5ccrdaalchHRKMj0s7UcikChBC8ROHKh8MqBr4S3mkhAA)

Comment: This gets me pretty close. I updated my post with a concrete example.

Comment: Another issue with a mapped type appears to be doing an update. See my post.

Comment: Not sure what `update()` is; it should likely be generic too, like `public update<K extends keyof T>(storeSlice: K, partialState: Partial<LoadableState<T[K]>>): void;`, and you must be careful with how you deal with those types. `merge()` and `set()` are not provided so I'm not sure what they need to do (*cries in [mcve]*) but computed keys like `{[storeSlice]: {}}` are [not going to be strongly typed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14473) the way you'll need.  You might need assertions. Note that I can't commit to keep responding if the scope of the question keeps expanding.

Comment: Ooops, I added comments for what they are. It's been a long day